# Font Embedding on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I need to store fonts with my data to make sure my documents appear the same on all machines.  To this end I am using TTEmbedFont to grab the bytes and save them out, then TTLoadEmbeddedFont to install the font once I have loaded it into memory.

Problem is I keep getting a E_FONTDATAINVALID whenever I try to use TTLoadEmbeddedFont.  It calls my READEMBEDPROC three times, asking for 4 bytes each time, then returns with the error.  My read proc looks like this:

```
unsigned long CFontLoaderDlg::ReadFontCallback(
_In_  void *lpvReadStream,
_In_  void *lpvBuffer,
_In_  const unsigned long cbBuffer
)
{
    CFontLoaderDlg *loader = static_cast<CFontLoaderDlg *>(lpvReadStream);
    size_t remaining = loader->m_font_bytes.size() - loader->m_pos;
    size_t bytes_to_read = (cbBuffer > remaining) ? remaining : cbBuffer;
    memcpy(lpvBuffer, &(loader->m_font_bytes[loader->m_pos]), bytes_to_read);
    loader->m_pos += bytes_to_read;
    return bytes_to_read;
}
```

The vector m_font_bytes holds the byes written from my call to TTEmbedFont.

My call to TTLoadFont looks like:

```
        LONG ret =  TTLoadEmbeddedFont(
        &hFontReference,
        TTLOAD_PRIVATE,
        &ulPrivStatus,
        LICENSE_PREVIEWPRINT,
        &ulStatus,
        ReadFontCallback,
        this,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr
        );
```

Has anyone had similar problems, or got this stuff working?

Comment: Which font formats does that function support? I can't find it on msdn, but assuming it's eot. So, a silly question, are you embedding an eot font? Another silly question, are you sure that lpvReadStream parameter should be this?

Comment: The TT functions support TrueType and Microsoft OpenType fonts.  The lpvReadStream is simply a pointer to something (as far as I can tell).  It is passed into the callback.  The documentation says it can be a "file handle or other" which is suitable vague.

Comment: I think it would be worth it trying to use the Embedded open type format. Have you thought about this alternative http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can't you distribute the font along with the data and install them non-embbed? If you can I can *give* you a working solution to check if exist/install fonts on windows platform. Otherwise with embbed I can't help I'm afraid

Comment: I want to be able to grab any font from a computer the app is running on.  This means pre-installing the fonts is not an option.

Comment: Can you add the code that writes the font? Often problems reading are really problems writing.

Comment: Also, lpvReadStream isn't actually used by TTLoadEmbeddedFont; it's passed to ReadFontCallback, which can use it however it wants.